# Properly Implementing Python Star Operator for a Custom Class

Tags: python

I have a Python class called `Point`, that is basically a holder for an `x` and `y` value with added functionality for finding distance, angle, and such with another `Point`.

For passing a point to some other function that may require the `x` and `y` to be separate, I would like to be able to use the `*` operator to unpack my `Point` to just the separate `x`, `y` values.

I have found that this is possible if I override `__getitem__` and raise a `StopIterationException` for any index beyond 1, with `x` corresponding to 0 and `y` to 1.

However it doesn't seem proper to raise a `StopIteration` when a `ValueError`/`KeyError` would be more appropriate for values beyond 1.

Does anyone know of the correct way to implement the `*` operator for a custom class? Preferably, a way that does not raise `StopIteration` through `__getitem__`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can implement the same by overriding the `__iter__` magic method, like this

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    def __iter__(self):
        return (self.__dict__[item] for item in sorted(self.__dict__))

def printer(x, y):
    print x, y

printer(*Point(2, 3))
```

**Output**

```
2 3
```

Comment: Cute, but why not just `def __iter__(self): return iter((self.x, self.y))` ?

Comment: Using `__dict__` makes it a generic solution, right?

Comment: It does, but it doesn't give us control over the order of the items, although having them sorted makes sense, I guess. Also, it doesn't work so well if the class has other attributes that we don't want to put into the iterator.

Comment: For the `Point` class, the dict will be sorted properly. However, implementing it for another class like `Size` (w, h) would give the reverse of how width and height are usually arranged. I like keeping it generic though. Would `__iter__(self): return (self[index] for index in range(len(self)))` work just as well? Assuming I have overridden `__getitem__` and `__len__` appropriately.

Comment: @LucasStertz It will work only if `self` is a list. Otherwise, you may have to use an `itemgetter`

Comment: Thanks! I set it all up and it works great. I also only had to override `__getitem__` for the alternative solution to work.

Comment: @LucasStertz : If you override `__getitem__` it's polite to users of your class (including yourself :) ) to also override `__setitem__`; it's kinda annoying to be able to do `x = Point[0]` but not `Point[0] = x`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it that uses `__dict__` but gives you precise control over the order without having to perform a sort on the keys for *every* access:

```
def __iter__(self): return (self.__dict__[item] for item in 'xy')
```

Of course, you could stash a sorted tuple, list or string of keys somewhere, but I think using a literal makes sense here.

And while I'm at it, here's one way to do the setter & getter methods.

```
def __getitem__(self, key): return (self.x, self.y)[key]

def __setitem__(self, key, val): setattr(self, 'xy'[key], val)
```